What would we be optimizing for if we were living for forgetting?
What if it's inevitable that one will develop Alzheimer's or a similar form of dementia if they live long enough? I was thinking whether living long enough might lead to inevitable cognitive decline and the reason why not everyone ends up having dementia is because they die before that happens. I'm really curious about exploring a hypothetical world where the focus of life shifts from remembering and holding onto experiences to actively forgetting them. The idea behind this question is to think about what values, goals, or behaviors would become important if forgetting, rather than remembering, was the hard-wired cognitive "default" of the human brain.

This is a good worldbuilding question! You might want to narrow this down a bit: one could optimise social aspects of life, genetic / evolutionary considerations, spiritual / inner life considerations, cultural aspects, religious aspects. The Stack Exchange model ask you to provide a narrowly focused question; and we'll give you on point and creative answers from which you could potentially choose one that suits your fictional world best!

Please pick tags which actually apply to your question. I have removed 4 of them because they had nothing to do with what you are asking.

I'm not seeing this as a meaningful question, as stated.  When you say "the focus of life shifts...to actively forgetting" do you mean that at a certain point in each individual's life the focus shifts, or do you mean some abstract "the focus of all human existence"?  The former doesn't seem to be what's written, but the latter makes no sense - without memories I'd argue it's not a human brain and logically there are no memories to forget if the lifelong purpose has been forgetting.  Please clarify and, as @elemtilas says, narrow the scope down to something suitable for an answer here.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. (a) Per the [tour], we are not a discussion forum. You are expected to ask one specific question focusing on a reasonably objective and focused problem that can have a single best answer. Please read the following Help Center pages for additional information: [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask] and help center.

I do not understand this question at all; it seems to assume that we can speak meaningfully of "what values, goals, or behaviors" are important in the real world where most people do indeed remember things. Do humans actually have a common and well defined set of "values, goals, or behaviors"? From Sallust's lofty omnis homines summa ope niti decet, to Thomas à Kempis's Imitation of Christ, to Conan the Barbarian's crush your enemies, see them driven before you, and hear the lamentations of their women?

Human beings already are constantly forgetting things. We put events into short-term memory but never transfer them into long-term memory. We forget far more than we remember. That is how we are able to handle the day to day differences we already encounter. The real issue humans have is how to choose what to remember, not what to forget.

This reminds me a little bit of the movie Memento. And I think at least some people would focus more on strategies like the protagonist did, where you could "remember" in a sense, as long as you had a system. Awesome idea. Good luck.

Scenario A: We develop "dementia"
"Dementia" here means the state of forgetting more than remembering. Can be due to an illness or just by growing old or because of some meta-physical alternate-life-process.
In this case, nothing will change up to the point when this "dementia" kicks in. Then it diverges to scenario B:
Scenario B: "dementia" acts uncontrollably and randomly
We will forget anything and everything at random points in the continued life. It is not guaranteed to loose the most recent memories first.
Life would be increasingly difficult and a healing/solution is not possible. Also the point at which self-sustained living is impossible is totally unpredictable.
The effects range from "dying, because it was forgotten how to breathe" to "just being able to sit around and think but not speak anymore" to "largely unaffected because only meaningless memories are lost first" and anything in-between.
Scenario C: "Forgetting" as a meta-physical approach
If our brains are more wired to forgetting than remembering anything from the start / birth, we would not be able to develop as an individual and neither as a species at all.
We probably would have died out long time ago.
